# Get all servers located in OU in AD with C#

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap, ou

I am trying to collect all the server objects in a OU in AD with C#, but I am not successful.

I try to access the OU like this:

```
var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "NO", "OU=Servers");
```

Is this correct?

And I try to group with this:

```
var groupPrincipal = new GroupPrincipal(context, "*");
```

But that throws an error.

What is the right way to go about to access the objects in a OU?

Comment: Your question is not really clear. Are you trying to get all `Groups` in an `OU`?

Comment: @Burzum I am trying to get all objects and groups, yes.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. The Servers OU did not have any groups inside it. Only more OU's based on Windows Server version. So to access the servers inside the OU's I had to reference nested OU like this: OU=2012, OU=Servers.

I also had to drop GroupPrincipal.

To access the servers I used the code from "Enumerate Objects in a OU" at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18102/Howto-Almost-Everything-In-Active-Directory-via-C#19